# Python SQLAlchemy: помогите описать таблицы

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

### В комментариях к моделям написано, что за связи требуется сделать

---

P.s. Я хочу увидеть решение, чтобы при его анализе я понял, как оно работает, потому что мне ничего не понятно из документации (Во всяком случае, к сожалению, я не знаю базу данных, но мне срочно нужно разобраться в проблеме )

```
class Product(Base):
    """

    id -- primary int key
    name -- string column with max 64 chars
    article -- unique shop article int column
    items -- relation to ReceiptItems
    """
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = ...
    name = ...
    article = ...
    items = ...


class ReceiptItem(Base):
    """
    Corresponds to a line in a receipt

    id -- primary key int column
    receipt_id -- receipt foreign key column
    receipt -- relation to Receipt
    product_id -- product foreign key column
    product -- relation to Product
    quantity -- quantity of sold product in ReceiptItem
    price -- price of sold product in ReceiptItem

    Constraints:
      - Receipt MUST NOT contain two ReceiptItems for same product
    """
    __tablename__ = 'receipt_item'

    id = ...
    receipt_id = ...
    receipt = ...
    product_id = ...
    product = ...
    quantity = ...
    price = ...


class Receipt(Base):
    """

    id -- primary key  int column
    completed_at -- datetime column
    items -- relation to ReceiptItems
    """
    __tablename__ = 'receipt'
    id = ...
    completed_at = ...
    items = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерную структуру накидал. Остальные связи сами настроите:

```
MyApp = Flask(__name__)
MyApp.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'ИМЯ_СУБД://ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ:ПАРОЛЬ_БД$$@IP_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА:ПОРТ/ИМЯ_БД'
MyApp.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(MyApp)
db.init_app(MyApp)

class ReceiptItem(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'receipt_item'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    receipt_id = ...
    receipt =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('receipt.id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = ...
    quantity = ...
    price = ...

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False, nullable=False)
    article = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False, nullable=False)
    items = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('receipt_item.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.id},{self.name},{self.article},{self.items}"

class Receipt(db.Model):
    """

    id -- primary key  int column
    completed_at -- datetime column
    items -- relation to ReceiptItems
    """
    __tablename__ = 'receipt'
    id = ...
    completed_at = ...
    items = ...


db.create_all()
```

Comment: Благодарю!)))))

Comment: Тут такое дело, я попробовал сам всё дописать и ничего не вышло(((

Comment: Ну Вы должны еще импортировать много чего, например: 
db = SQLAlchemy(MyApp)

Comment: у меня это всё импортировано, я использую декларацию, просто я не понимаю SQLAlchemy от слова СОВСЕМ, а связи сделать как-то нужно и пройти тесты

Comment: Я Вам Предлагаю нарисовать таблички на бумаге и соединить строки таблиц - что откуда берется. Таким образом Вы сможете через "db.ForeignKey()" указать ссылки на другие таблицы.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую